# What's the best way to set a variable outside a loop before setting up the loop?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to use the following code to output a list of events that are on a date greater than or equal to today's date:

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'event') // setup my custom post type    
$todaysdate = blah blah //setup for today's date

// the wp loop  
query_posts($args); 

if ( (have_posts() && $eventdate >= $todaysdate)  ) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

$eventdate = blah blah // setup for the date of the event;

echo $event;

endwhile; endif;
```

The problem as you can see is that the IF is dependent on a variable that is within the loop.

What's the best way to set the variable outside the loop first?

Comment: Why don't you just run the while loop and move the if statement into the while loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That if should actually be inside the loop, like

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'event') // setup my custom post type    
$todaysdate = "blah blah"; //setup for today's date

// the wp loop  
query_posts($args); 

if ( (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

$eventdate = "blah blah"; // setup for the date of the event;

if($eventdate >= $todaysdate))

echo $event;

endif;

endwhile; endif;
```

**EDIT:**

`Thanks, this works fine, however, I want to output a set number of events (5 in total) which I've defined in $args. So $args sets up 5 events, but the second IF then filters out old events so I end up with less than 5.`

But that's the very same reason you have that if in first place. However if you mean that it should show 5 events that are after that date then the `wp_query` itself needs to be modified. See [Examples Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: Thanks, this works fine, however, I want to output a set number of events (5 in total) which I've defined in $args. So $args sets up 5 events, but the second IF then filters out old events so I end up with less than 5.

Comment: Great, thanks. I fixed it using $query = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'mydate', 'meta_value' => $todaysdate, 'meta_compare' => '>=' ) );

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing

```
if stuff from while iteration that doesn't exist yet
    while
```

Then you should be doing

```
while
    if stuff from current while iteration
```

Like you say: "The problem as you can see is that the IF is dependent on a variable that is within the loop."

You just structure your code so that what's needed exist at the point of your current execution. Just move the dependency to a proper location so it exists before you use it.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried moving the IF inside the WHILE but get a 'Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded'